# Can headphones with 1/8" inputs be used with a mixing board's aux sends that output to XLR or 1/4"?

Tags: mixing, headphones, aux-sends, converter

I am looking at mixing boards that have aux sends. [This one uses XLR aux](https://www.thomann.de/intl/behringer_x_air_xr16.htm) and [this one uses 1/4" aux](https://www.thomann.de/intl/behringer_x_air_xr12.htm).

Can I use a converter to listen to the aux send on headphones that take 1/8" input? For example, using a [XLR-to-1/8"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073LPHGND) or [1/4" to 1/8"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QNFGH61)?

Would I need additional hardware, like headphone amplifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a headphone amplifier that has balanced input